# Applying Numerical Differentiation on the solution of a FindRoot problem

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I would like to numerically differentiate the solution of a `FindRoot` problem in Mathematica, I have been struggling with this for two days and cannot find the way to do it. I simplify the problem below (so indeed here `FindRoot` is not really needed):

Suppose I have two equations:

```
2 b x - 3 b + 2 y = 0

b y - x - a = 0
```

where $x$ and $y$ are the variables to be found, and $a$ and $b$ are exogenous parameters.

Then, `x = (3b^2-2a) / (2*b^2+2)` and `dx/da= -1 / (b^2+1)`

Thus, `dx/da` evaluated at a=2 & b=2 is equal to -0.2.

In Mathematica the code would look something like this but it does not work to me:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]

solution[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := 
  FindRoot[{2bx - 3b + 2y == 0, b*y - x - a == 0}, {{x, 2.}, {y, 2.}}]

ND[solution[2, 2][[1]], {x, 1}, 1]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
solution[a_?NumericQ,b_?NumericQ]:=FindRoot[{2b*x-3b+2y==0,b*y-x-a==0},
                                            {{x,2.},{y,2.}}];
xsolution[a_?NumericQ,b_?NumericQ]:=x/.solution[a,b];
ysolution[a_?NumericQ,b_?NumericQ]:=y/.solution[a,b];

(* numerical differentiation *)
NumericalCalculus`ND[xsolution[a,2],
                     {a,1}, (* <--- first derivative *)
                     2]     (* <--- at the point 2 *)
(* -0.2 *)
```

**Comments.**

- In OPs code, `ND[solution[2,2][[1]],...]` note that `solution[2,2][[1]]` is a constant and the derivative will be zero.
- Just writing `ND[solution[a,2][[1]],...]` is problematic since `solution[a,2][[1]]` does not evaluate yet and will give the `First` of the expression which is `a`. Therefore I used `xsolution` to delay that evaluation.
- Also, OPs code has `ND[...,{x,1},...]` when what we actually want is differentiation with respect to `a` meaning `ND[...,{a,1},...]`.

Comment: great! thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for! very helpful!

Answer (score 6):

One idea is to just augment your [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot) call with information about the derivative. For your example, this might look like:

```
f[x_, y_] := 2 b x - 3 b + 2 y
g[x_, y_] := b y - x - a

FindRoot[
    {
        f[x[a], y[a]] == 0, 
        g[x[a], y[a]] == 0, 
        D[f[x[a], y[a]], a] == 0,
        D[g[x[a], y[a]], a] == 0
    } /. {a->2, b->2}, 
    {x[2], 1}, {y[2], 1}, {x'[2], 1}, {y'[2], 1}
]
```

> {x[2] -> 0.8, y[2] -> 1.4, x'[2] -> -0.2, y'[2] -> 0.4}

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, but I needed to numerically differentiate the solutions.

Comment: @my2cents It is quite often possible to avoid the need for numerical differentiation, which is good because obtaining a good result numerically can be quite finicky.

Comment: Your are certainly right, but unfortunately this time I cannot avoid numerical differentiation.